# How does trigger logic app when AZURE SQL insertion occurred

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

My SQL Server seems to be connected correctly because database and table name is suggested in logic app.

[image]

However, the logic app trigger history all skipped.

Output log is here:

```
{
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Retry-After": "15",
        "x-ms-request-id": "7d7786b9-b7db-4958-a1ef-7c651a31f3a0",
        "OData-Version": "4.0",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Date": "Thu, 06 Feb 2020 09:31:01 GMT",
        "Location": "https://logic-apis-eastus.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/7835fbfdd13e4975ab4d9adbf41059e2/v2/datasets/default,default/tables/%255Bdbo%255D.%255Btransactions%255D/onnewitems?triggerstate=",
        "Content-Length": "113",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "body": {
        "@odata.context": "https://sql-eus.azconn-eus.p.azurewebsites.net/v2/$metadata#items",
        "value": []
    }
}
```

I use query editor to simulate when '項目が作成された時' by this query

```
INSERT INTO transactions (txFrom, txTo)
VALUES ('a', 'b')
```

The `INSERT` succeeds, so I expect "when item is created trigger" should be run, but nothing happens.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Azure SQL.

Azure SQL table should have primary ID to trigger logic up.

I changed table definition from

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
    txFrom TEXT,
    txTo TEXT
);
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    txFrom TEXT,
    txTo TEXT
);
```

this solved the problem.